The meaning of a sentence and conjunctions
I'd like to say that I will buy something for my let's say son now only if already and  reguraly gets good grades. I am pretty sure I could do this like this

I will you buy that phone now only if you get grades- as I said I mean if you already have good grades not once you get in the future. That's why I think it is fine. Otherwise I would need to get rid of "now".

But, now let's go to my actual question. Let's say I know my son already gets good grades so "if" doesn't really show that meaning. Could I say

I will buy you this phone now when/while you get good grades- meaning I will buy you this phone now since you already get good grades reguraly for some time.

Is my understanding of 1 and 2 examples correct?

Normally only if you get good grades strongly implies in the future (feasibly the addressee has already taken the tests, but hasn't yet been told his grades). Use only if you have good grades if the speaker doesn't know the addressee's grades for tests already taken, but the addressee does. I don't understand what you mean in case 2. If he has good grades so far, are you going to buy the phone now or not? How can you or he know if he will continue to get good grades in the future?

You should use "because" if the reason you're buying the phone is due to his existing good grades. "I'm buying you this phone because you got good grades."

You already seem to know how to express it using "since" so why not use that?

Also please use a spell checker: "reguraly" isn't a word and your punctuation is a bit off.

Piece of advice: Use a spell checker because sloppiness will not impress anyone.

In the example, using "only if" is confusing.  Try something like "so"

You're getting good grades, so I'll buy you that phone.

or "because"

I'll buy you that phone because you are getting good grades.

Notice how this is much clearer and avoids "if". There is no "condition" in the first example.  The facts are known (he is already getting good grades).
It doesn't make sense to say "I'll buy you the phone now if you continue to get good grades in the future" (since the future is unknown)  The sentence is grammatical but doesn't make pragmatic sense.  It would be fine to say "I'll buy you that phone for your birthday if you continue to get good grades".  Moreover, in that sentence you would pragmatically understand "if" to mean "if, and only if" That is you would understand that if the boy doesn't get good grades, he won't get the phone.

Artur, your knowledge is faulty.
You wrote:

I will you buy that phone now only if you get grades- as I said I mean if you already have good grades not once you get in the future. That's why I think it is fine. Otherwise I would need to get rid of "now".

The clause that expresses that the son must be already getting good grades is not the main clause  ( "I will buy you that phone now") but the subordinate clause.
This is wrong:

I will you buy that phone now only if you get grades

This is what you need to say:

Now that you are getting good grades, I will buy you that phone.

You are putting now in the wrong clause.
